# two possible typedef struct syntax options, there is any different?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I want to define a struct for linked list,
from the next two options,
one of theme is better? both of them will work? what is the different and which one will u use?

```
typedef struct suppliers * SUP;
    typedef struct suppliers{
    int num;
    int moths;
    SUP next;
} su;
```

and the other options is:

```
typedef supplier *suppliers
typedef struct supplier{
    int num;
    int moths;
    struct supplier *next;
} supplier;
```

Comment: The second option won't compile. Fix your question.

Comment: both of these have pathological naming, perhaps you should encapsulate  whatever you want inside a node<T> template

Comment: @SteveCox What is a template - in C?

Comment: It does not make a lot of sense to typedef pointers.

Comment: Why this strange indention?

Answer (score 5):

My preferred version:

```
struct supplier{
    int num;
    int moths;
    struct supplier *next;
};
```

typedefs on struct, enum or union are hiding useful information.

Comment: The first `struct supplier;` is unnecessary. Nevertheless, +1.

Comment: yeah, why the forward decl?

Comment: @JosephQuinsey Minority in what way?

Comment: @glglgl: I agree with jag's statement that "typedefs on struct, enum or union are hiding useful information", with the exceptions being of having a _small_ number of types which are used everywhere in your application, or when you deliberately want to hide information, as in an opaque data type, or when you are obliged to write C++-like code. But, judging from code samples posted on SO, or written by my coworkers, most people prefer to typedef _everything_.

Comment: @JosephQuinsey Ok. I just wasn't clear about the relation of code that excessively uses `typedef` to code that doesn't.